# How to fix my linkedHashSet insertion order

Tags: java

I have 3 departments added to my

`Set<String> workFlowDepartmentList = new LinkedHashSet<>();`

and they should be added by who comes first. But, my set adds them in ascending order. How do I solve this? Thanks.

I even tried to manually add the 3 departments to my set based on who comes/added first by using `add();` and it worked.

```
//xhtml
<h:selectManyMenu styleClass="chosen-select2" id="input-workFlowCode"
                  value="#{EmployeeClearanceController.workFlowDepartmentList}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{EmployeeClearanceController.departmentList}" var="dept"
                  itemValue="#{dept.departmentCode}" itemLabel="#{dept.name}"/>
         f:ajax execute="change"/>
</h:selectManyMenu>   

//controller
/* What i tried to add manually [worked]
workFlowDepartmentList.add("D0002-25");
workFlowDepartmentList.add("D0002-13");
workFlowDepartmentList.add("D0002-26");
*/

for(String dept : workFlowDepartmentList){
    System.out.println("dept: " + dept);
}
```

In my `<h:selectManyMenu>`, I have selected `D0002-25, D0002-13, D0002-26` in that order.
I expect the output to be the like that in same order. But, the actual output I got from my controller:
`dept: D0002-13
 dept: D0002-25
 dept: D0002-26`

Comment: You should check order of insertion of elements in LinkedHashSet because its always keep order of element.

Comment: LinkedHashSet will preserve insertion order . Looks like the bug is with front end code . Can you recheck?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thanks Chetan Joshi and JavaUser. I will check my LinkedHashSet and my front end code.

Answer (score -1):

use TreeSet  instead of LinkedHashSet..

```
  TreeSet<String> workFlowDepartmentList = new TreeSet<>();
            workFlowDepartmentList.add("D0002-25");
            workFlowDepartmentList.add("D0002-13");
            workFlowDepartmentList.add("D0002-26");

            for (String dept : workFlowDepartmentList) {
                System.out.println("dept: " + dept);
            }

Output be like this::
dept: D0002-13
dept: D0002-25
dept: D0002-26
```

Comment: TreeSet will sort the elements so it wont maintain the insertion order.

Comment: @javaUser  but at the same time he can't sort and maintain insertion order, so better to use TreeSet